# Reduce Bundle size of SKMAPS

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I have been working with SKMaps... I had included .skm files of two cities and had also included the frameworks using cocoapods.

After adding the frame works and basic navigation using routing code to my project, I found that my app bundle size became 440MB and when I tried to archive the project, the .ipa file was of about 80 MB.

Is there any way to reduce the bundle size,as I want to make the app size as small as possible?

```
target 'Maps' do
pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK'
pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools'
end
```